# regex to get all text outside of brackets

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to grab any text outside of brackets with a regex.

**Example string**

> Josie Smith [3996 COLLEGE AVENUE, SOMETOWN, MD 21003]Mugsy Dog Smith
>   [2560 OAK ST, GLENMEADE, WI 14098]

I'm able to get the text *inside* the square brackets successfully with:

```
addrs = re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]", example_str)
print addrs
[u'3996 COLLEGE AVENUE, SOMETOWN, MD 21003',u'2560 OAK ST, GLENMEADE, WI 14098']
```

but I'm having trouble getting anything *outside* of the square brackets.  I've tried something like the following:

```
names = re.findall(r"(.*?)\[.*\]+", example_str)
```

but that only finds the first name:

```
print names
[u'Josie Smith ']
```

So far I've only seen a string containing one to two `name [address]` combos, but I'm assuming there could be any number of them in a string.

Comment: can the brackets be nested

Comment: @aaronman  I'm assuming there will NOT be any nested brackets.  good question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If there are no nested brackets, you can just do this:

```
re.findall(r'(.*?)\[.*?\]', example_str)
```

---

However, you don't even really need a regex here. Just split on brackets:

```
(s.split(']')[-1] for s in example_str.split('['))
```

---

The only reason your attempt didn't work:

```
re.findall(r"(.*?)\[.*\]+", example_str)
```

… is that you were doing a non-greedy match within the brackets, which means it was capturing everything from the first open bracket to the last close bracket, instead of capturing just the first pair of brackets.

---

Also, the `+` on the end seems wrong. If you had `'abc [def][ghi] jkl[mno]'`, would you want to get back `['abc ', '', ' jkl']`, or `['abc ', ' jkl']`? If the former, don't add the `+`. If it's the latter, do—but then you need to put the whole bracketed pattern in a non-capturing group: `r'(.*?)(?:\[.*?\])+`.

---

If there might be additional text after the last bracket, the `split` method will work fine, or you could use `re.split` instead of `re.findall`… but if you want to adjust your original regex to work with that, you can.

In English, what you want is any (non-greedy) substring before a bracket-enclosed substring *or* the end of the string, right?

So, you need an alternation between `\[.*?\]` and `$`. Of course you need to group that in order to write the alternation, and you don't want to capture the group. So:

```
re.findall(r"(.*?)(?:\[.*?\]|$)", example_str)
```

Comment: What if there's any text *after*  the last pair of brackets? (referring only to your regex; your splitting solution works)

Comment: Ah yes, that all makes sense.  I like the `split` solution better myself.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: You can add that in the same style as the OP's original regex; the bit at all complicated is that the obvious way to write it needs a non-capturing group. Edited the answer to show how.

Comment: The `\]+` is wrong anyhow, because it repeats only the bracket, not the bracketed text.

Comment: Good point. As I said, I don't think the OP wanted it anyway, but I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 5):

If there are never nested brackets:

```
([^[\]]+)(?:$|\[)
```

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Josie Smith [3996 COLLEGE AVENUE, SOMETOWN, MD 21003]Mugsy Dog Smith [2560 OAK ST, GLENMEADE, WI 14098]'
>>> re.findall(r'([^[\]]+)(?:$|\[)', s)
['Josie Smith ', 'Mugsy Dog Smith ']
```

Explanation:

```
([^[\]]+)   # match one or more characters that are not '[' or ']' and place in group 1
(?:$|\[)    # match either a '[' or at the end of the string, do not capture
```

Comment: This one works better because it doesn't return an empty string like @abamert's does

Comment: This captures the ending **[** isn't? Or at least that's what I get: https://regex101.com/r/G43H7X/1 

I think that a slightly better versing would be `([^[\]]+)(?:$|(?=\[))` so that only the content is extracted

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go with regex and still handle nested brackets, you can go with:

```
import re
expr = re.compile("(?:^|])([^[\]]+)(?:\[|$)")

print(expr.findall("myexpr[skip this[and this]]another[and skip that too]"))
```

This will yield `['myexpr', 'another']`.

The idea is to match anything between the beginning of the string or a `]` and the end of the string or a `[`.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
 outside = re.findall(r"[^[]+(?=\[[^]]*]|$)", example_str)
```

In other words: All that is not an opening square bracket followed by something inside square brackets or the end of the string