# Regex match only if not in context

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, neovim

Engine: Vim RegEx

Input:

```
\begin{thoerm}\label{ABC_for_all}
    If the ABC is a common good, $ABC(places)$ includes everything.
\end{thorem}

We will now prove Threorem \ref{ABC_for_all}.
```

Expression:

```
(?<!(\\label|\\ref)\{\w*)ABC(?!\w*\})
```

Expected:

I want to match (and replace in neovim) "ABC", but only if it is not part of a name (so not in a \label{...} or \ref{...} context.

Result:

Doesn't work.

I know how to replace it if it occurs within the context:

```
:s/(\\label\{\w*)ABC(\w\})*/\1alphaber\2/g
```

But not the occurrences outside of it.

Lookahead didn't work, because the ABC may occur somewhere within the label command, thus I need variable width. I also was unable to figure out how to turn a capture group into the actual match. It seems like such a common case, but everything I found so far didn't include it.

Comment: Regular expressions are not good at checking context like this. A real parse is a better choice. This looks like TeX, it shouldn't be hard to find a TeX parser.

Comment: But the weird thing is, it is quite easy to replace the matches within the context. However, I ramain unable to replace all except them, which seems to be a very dual problem.

Comment: They're not really duals. It's easy to represent "inside" because you can write `start.*end`. But "outside" is hard because something that's not inside one pair could still be inside another pair.

Comment: you can use a lookahead to match a string that doesn't include the start/end patterns, but that will still match something inside.

Comment: When the context is delimited by specific bracketing characters, like `[...]` you can use the aproaches here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284947/regex-to-get-all-text-outside-of-brackets but that doesn't work when it's bracketed by keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was told this in not possible with regex, my workaround was as follows:

1. Rename everyhting within the specified context by some MARKER.
2. Replace everything else.
3. Replace the MARKER by the original.

Each time using regex.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex do the job:

```
:%s/\({.*\)\@<!ABC/OK/g
```

Since `\label{...}` or `\ref{...}` have both `{`, we only need to negatively match that with `\({.*\)\@<!`.

Comment: I am not quite clear what is happening here, in particular, what \@ does. However, I want to point out that for my setting ABC should be replaced within "\mycommand{..ABC..}" and also in "\ref{....}...ABC".